# Is there a way to compare a date against a table that can sort it in one of three categories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to compare a set of events that are date/time stamped against a table that can categorize it in three different buckets.

This table has four columns:

```
Column 1: Date
Column 2: Rotation 1
Column 3: Rotation 2
Column 4: Rotation 3
```

There are 356 rows (one for each day) and then each column has either 'Night shift', 'Day shift' or 'Days off'.

If I have a dataframe with a bunch of entries that have date and time, can I set a rule to compare it to this other table?

- If the time is betwee 5AM and 5PM, find that day in the other table and 
     output the corresponding 'Rotation 1', 'Rotation 2' or 'Rotation 3'
- If the time is between 5PM and 5AM, do the same as above.

Then next to each datetime on the Pandas dataframe, I'm trying to have one more column appear with Rotation 1, 2 or 3 depending on which one fits there.

I was able to put together a Frankenstein v-lookup nightmare in excel, I'm new to Pandas but I feel it can be a much cleaner process.

Add one column to the dataframe with the corresponding rotation based on the date and time.

Comment: This question is unclear about exactly what you're looking for in your dataframe. I'm *guessing* that you're trying to turn a table that maps from date and rotation to assignment (day, night, off) into one that maps from date and time to rotation (so if the time is in the day, it picks whatever rotation has the day shift, and if at night, it picks whichever has the night shift). Is that right? Because you don't currently explain what "corresponding 'Rotation 1', 'Rotation 2' or 'Rotation 3'" means, nor why you care about the time if you "do the same as above" for night hours..

Comment: First of all thank you for your feedback.

I put together an image to help explain, please let me know if it clarifies.

[IMAGE](https://imgur.com/a/jXbcPOF)